Set a default namespace when using openxml
I have the following piece of SQL
DECLARE @h int;
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @h OUTPUT, N'<root xmlns:a="urn:1"><a:Elem>T</a:Elem></root>', '<ns xmlns:a="urn:1" />';


--WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'a')
SELECT * FROM openxml(@h, '/root/a:Elem')
      WITH (Col1 varchar(20) 'text()');
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @h;

This gives me :
Col1
T
as expected.
I would like to get rid of the 'a:', something like
DECLARE @h int;
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @h OUTPUT, N'<root xmlns:a="urn:1"><a:Elem>T</a:Elem></root>', '<ns xmlns:a="urn:1" />';


WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'a')
SELECT * FROM openxml(@h, '/root/Elem')
      WITH (Col1 varchar(20) 'text()');
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @h;

But this does not work.
Yes, I could

insert the namespaces or
change the code the more modern using nodes, query, value instead of prepare, open, remove
but

I have inherited a LOT of old SQL code, an I want to exploit this option before doing a lot of work.
SO: is there any way you can set a default namespace for openxml in SQL Server?

I'm inclined to ask the question: why? <root> and <Elem> are in different namespaces so the XPath /root/Elem would be selecting for them both in whichever is the default namespace and never match. Aside from using a wildcard with openxml(@h, '/root/*') - which would return any element, not just Elem from the urn:1 namespace - no.

Also note that openxml doesn't work with WITH XMLNAMESPACES(), the namespaces and prefixes to use in the queries are defined in sp_xml_preparedocument's third parameter.

You can use: *:Elem to ignore the namespace thingy when refering to an element, but not sure you can completely remove them

Microsoft proprietary OPENXML() and its companions sp_xml_preparedocument and sp_xml_removedocument are kept just for backward compatibility with the obsolete SQL
Server 2000. Their use is diminished just to very few fringe cases.
Starting from SQL Server 2005 onwards, it is strongly recommended to re-write your SQL and switch it to XQuery.
Also, OPENXML() cannot take advantage of XML indexes while XQuery methods can.

Hi Yitzhak:
I fully agree, but as stated, I have a lot of legacy here.

@siggemannen openxml is extremely limited. *:Elem would give you an XML parsing error not because it's invalid XPath but because, among many other things, openxml just doesn't support wildcard prefixes.

@AlwaysLearning oh really, sorry about that, i was testing some code and "forgot" i had moved to nodes methods in some branch :) Perhaps: REPLACE(@xml, '<a:', '<') can work for Op, but if he has code that is already working, why bother with changes, unless someone suddently has added some namespaces
